# Gitkraken with TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, gitkraken

I upgraded to gitkraken 2.2 and I'm not able to login to TFS 2015 repositories anymore. Asking username and password and my current windows credentials doesn't work. Tried with active directory domain domain\myuser but didn't work as well. Stuck to use it now since prompting for any commands. I have no issues by doing git commands via git bash or any other git tool (like git extensions)
Repositories are using HTTP and not HTTPS, could it be an issue as well ?

TFS Server : TFS 2015 update 1

Comment: Are you able to login TFS 2015 repositories with the previous version of Gitkraken?

Comment: Yes i use until git kraken 2.1 and had no issues until then. Worked really well

Answer (score 0):

I just tested Gitkraken 2.2 with my TFS 2015 Update 3 and TFS 2017, both can be connected without issue.

If you could login TFS 2015 repositories with the previous version of Gitkraken, I'm afraid you need to upgrade your TFS 2015.1 to TFS 2015.3 or later version.

Comment: I cannot upgrade TFS to greater version as used by all company in different locations. Don't think it should be server changing because of client issues. Works with git bash and git extensions UI

Comment: @StevenJ, Do you try on another client machine with Gitkraken 2.2? If the issue persists on another client machine, I suggest you open a ticket on Gitkraken side to see whether Gitkraken 2.2 support TFS 2015.1 any more. Otherwise, you would use Gitkraken 2.1 as a workaround.

Comment: Yes i will test from another machine when i have time. Issue on current machine even if i download 2.1 it silently upgrades to 2.2, do you know why ?

Comment: You would need to get support from Gitkraken side.

Answer (score 0):

Works now with latest release 2.3.3.
Thanks Gitkraken for your nice work